# Angular 2: [(ngModel)] not working when data-provide='datepicker'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have defined an input in my html which provides the datepicker.

```html
<div class="icon-input icon-calender">
  <input [(ngModel)]="startDate" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="input-sm form-control" placeholder="From date" data-provide="datepicker"/>
  <i class="arrow"></i>
</div>
```

I have initialized the startDate (Date) object in the typescript file. Two-way databinding is not working on startDate.

```js
startDate: Date = new Date();

apply(){
    console.log(this.startDate);
    console.log(this.startDate.getTime());
  }
```

How is the two-way databinding possible when using datepicker on the input tag?

Comment: What do you mean by "Two-way databinding is not working"? Does it work when you remove the `data-provide='datepicker'`? Which version of Bootstrap do you use? Have you checked how Bootstrap modifies the input element?

Comment: yes, it works when i remove  data-provide='datepicker'. I am using Bootstrap v3.3.7. Bootstrap is able to read the input, but I'm unable to read the same input in the typescript file. So that I can replicate the same, could you please tell me how bootstrap does that?